# Position of an image not updating the way I want it to in PYGAME

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

My objective is to make a cannon fire a cannonball in a linear path. I have been playing around with some algorithms for quite a bit, but I cannot get one fluid motion, instead the position updates in chunks and I'm not sure how to evade this problem. Here is my code:

```
 import pygame
from functools import partial

pygame.init()

display_width = 700
display_height = 500
display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))

cannonImg = 'C:/Users/student/Desktop/cannon.png'
skyImg = 'C:/Users/student/Desktop/sky.png'
cannonballImg = 'C:/Users/student/Desktop/cannonball.png'
cannon = pygame.image.load(cannonImg)
sky = pygame.image.load(skyImg)
cannonball = pygame.image.load(cannonballImg)

blue = (0,0,200)
light_blue = (0,0,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (200,0,0)
light_red = (255,0,0)

smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 25)
medfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Algerian", 50)
largefont = pygame.font.SysFont("Algerian", 85)

altSmall = pygame.font.SysFont("Algerian",20)
altMed = pygame.font.SysFont("Algerian",30)
altLarge = pygame.font.SysFont("Algerian",75)
extrasmall = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",15)

def text_objects(text, color,size = "small"):

    if size == "small":
        textSurface = smallfont.render(text, True, color)
    if size == "medium":
        textSurface = medfont.render(text, True, color)
    if size == "large":
        textSurface = largefont.render(text, True, color)

    if size == "altMed":
        textSurface = altMed.render(text,True,color)

    if size == "altSmall":
        textSurface = altSmall.render(text,True,color)

    if size == "medFont":
        textSurface = medfont.render(text,True,color)

    if size == "smallFont":
        textSurface = smallfont.render(text,True,color)

    if size == "extraSmall":
        textSurface = extrasmall.render(text,True,color)

    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',200)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    game_loop()

class Button():

    text = str()
    x = int()
    y = int()
    width = int()
    height = int()
    inactive_color = None
    active_color = None
    action = str()
    active = bool()

    def __init__(self,text,x,y,width,height,inactive_color,active_color,action,text_color,text_size,active):
        self.text = text
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.inactive_color = inactive_color
        self.active_color = active_color
        self.action = action
        self.text_color = text_color
        self.text_size = text_size
        self.active = active

    def nothing():
        pass

    def handle_event(self,event):

        if self.is_hovered() and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            self.action()

    def text_to_button(self,surface):
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects(self.text,self.text_color,self.text_size)
        textRect.center = ((self.x+(self.width/2)), self.y+(self.height/2))
        surface.blit(textSurf, textRect)


    def is_hovered(self):
        cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        return self.x + self.width > cur[0] > self.x and self.y + self.height > cur[1] > self.y

    def drawButton(self, surface):

        if self.active:
            pygame.draw.rect(surface,self.inactive_color,[self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height])

        if self.is_hovered() and self.active:
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.active_color,[self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height])

        self.text_to_button(surface)

def nothing():
    pass

class kinematic():

    obj_x = 110
    obj_y = 240
    v = 0
    t = 0

    def __init__(self,v,t):
        self.v = v
        self.t = t

    def addOneV(self):
        self.v += 1

    def addOneXI(self):
        self.xi += 1

    def addOneT(self):
        self.t += 1

    def reset(self):
        self.v = 0
        self.t = 0
        self.obj_x = 125
        self.obj_y = 240

    def calculatePos(self):
        n = 0
        while n < self.t+1:
            self.obj_x = self.t * 10
            self.obj_y = self.v * n
            n += 1

def programLoop():

    object1 = kinematic(0,10)
    reset = Button("Reset",400,25,100,75,red,light_red,object1.reset,black,"smallFont",True)

    programExit = False

    while not programExit:
        addVelocity = Button("Velocity: %i " % object1.v + "m/s",50, 25,150,50,red,light_red,object1.addOneV,black,"extraSmall",True)
        addTime = Button("Time: %i " % object1.t + "s",50, 75,150,50,red,light_red,object1.addOneT,black,"extraSmall",True)
        fireCannon = Button("Fire",display_width/2 - 75,25,125,75,red,light_red,object1.calculatePos,black,"smallFont",True)


        for evt in pygame.event.get():

            fireCannon.handle_event(evt)
            addVelocity.handle_event(evt)
            addTime.handle_event(evt)
            reset.handle_event(evt)
            if evt.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()


        display.blit(sky,[0,0])
        display.blit(cannon,[25,300])
        fireCannon.drawButton(display)
        addVelocity.drawButton(display)
        addTime.drawButton(display)
        reset.drawButton(display)
        display.blit(cannonball,[object1.obj_x,object1.obj_y])
        display.blit(cannonball,[object1.obj_x,object1.obj_y])

        pygame.display.update()

programLoop()
```

Thanks! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the images?

Comment: You would normally just update the position of the object by adding the velocity each frame. I'm not really sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: So I am currently confused on how to do that. How to make the position of the image update frame by frame, instead of moving in one big chunk like it does now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the velocity of the object to its position in each frame in order to move it. I also pass the [delta time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_time) to the `update` method and multiply it with the velocity to make the object move `self.v` pixels per second.

```
import pygame


pygame.init()

display_width = 700
display_height = 500
display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))

CANNONBALL = pygame.Surface((30, 30))
CANNONBALL.fill((90, 90, 90))

LIGHT_BLUE = (140,220,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
RED = (200,0,0)
LIGHT_RED = (255,0,0)

SMALLFONT = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 25)


def text_objects(text, color, font):  # You can pass the font object.
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, color)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


class Button:

    def __init__(self, text, x, y, width, height, inactive_color, active_color,
                 action, text_color, font, active):
        self.text = text
        # Create a rect instead of the separate x, y, w, h attributes.
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
        self.inactive_color = inactive_color
        self.active_color = active_color
        self.action = action
        self.text_color = text_color
        self.font = font  # The font is an attribute now.
        self.active = active

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if self.is_hovered() and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            self.action()

    def text_to_button(self, surface):
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects(self.text, self.text_color, self.font)
        textRect.center = self.rect.center
        surface.blit(textSurf, textRect)

    def is_hovered(self):
        return self.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

    def drawButton(self, surface):
        if self.active:
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.inactive_color, self.rect)
        if self.is_hovered() and self.active:
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.active_color, self.rect)

        self.text_to_button(surface)


class Kinematic:

    def __init__(self, v):
        self.obj_x = 110
        self.obj_y = 240
        self.v = v
        self.started = False

    def reset(self):
        self.started = False
        self.v = 0
        self.obj_x = 125
        self.obj_y = 240

    def start(self):
        self.started = True

    def update(self, dt):
        if self.started:
            # Just add the velocity to the position to
            # move the object.
            # Multiply the velocity by the delta time
            # to move `self.v` pixels per second.
            self.obj_x += self.v * dt


def programLoop():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    object1 = Kinematic(0)

    # Callback functions to modify the object and update the button texts.
    def add_v():
        object1.v += 10
        addVelocity.text = f"Velocity: {object1.v} m/s"

    def reset():
        object1.reset()
        addVelocity.text = f"Velocity: {object1.v} m/s"

    reset = Button(
        "Reset", 400, 25, 100, 75, RED, LIGHT_RED,
        reset, BLACK, SMALLFONT, True)
    addVelocity = Button(
        f"Velocity: {object1.v} m/s", 50, 25, 150, 50,
        RED, LIGHT_RED, add_v, BLACK, SMALLFONT, True)
    fireCannon = Button(
        "Fire", display_width/2 - 75, 25, 125, 75, RED, LIGHT_RED,
        object1.start, BLACK, SMALLFONT, True)
    # You can put all buttons into a list and use for loops to
    # draw them and pass the events.
    buttons = [reset, addVelocity, fireCannon]

    dt = 0
    programExit = False

    while not programExit:
        for evt in pygame.event.get():
            for button in buttons:
                button.handle_event(evt)
            if evt.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        # Call the `update` method once per frame.
        object1.update(dt)  # Pass the delta time to the object.

        display.fill(LIGHT_BLUE)
        for button in buttons:
            button.drawButton(display)
        display.blit(CANNONBALL, [object1.obj_x, object1.obj_y])

        pygame.display.update()
        # dt is the time that has passed since the last clock.tick call.
        dt = clock.tick(60) / 1000


programLoop()
pygame.quit()
```

I've also tried to improve and simplify a few more things. Take a look at the comments.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. I have since figured out how to fix my logic problem, but this makes much more sense. Thanks for taking the time to set this up!